# Cache library not loading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have got an error while loading cache library in codeigniter(2.1.3).
What it is saying is this:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested class: cache

My Code Looks like this

```
if (!$data['foo'] = $this->cache->file->get('details')) {
        $data['foo'] = $this->foo->getdetails();
        $this->cache->file->save('details', $data['foo'], 600);
    }
```

My autoload file is like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session','driver','cache');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi every body i got the answer of this issue.

Finally i made a custom library and call that in my autoload file. it solved my problem.

and The Code is here

```
class CallCache  {

public function __construct($config = array())
{
            $ci = &get_instance();
            $ci->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file')); 
}
}
```

Finally Thank God

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are not missing the load library function of CI... look like you are not loading the class..

> From within any of your Controller functions you can initialize your class using the standard: $this->load->library('someclass');

try this

```
$this->load->library('cache');  //library name  // put it on your controller..
```

here is the [useguide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Comment: already did that.
Working fine on my local but not on server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to load your cache library previously. You can do it this way:

```
$this->load->library('cache');
```

Or you can put the cache library in your autoload.php

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation','session','driver','cache');

Comment: Hi every body i got the answer of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to rename folder name from: "libraries/cache" to "libraries/Cache" in system folder :)

Loader uses ucfirst() to uppercase first letter folder name and search in it to find driver.

Answer (score 0):

how about you compare the versions of php in both your local and server.. I did this awhile back in regards to charset utf-8 and it turns out that CI can't work well if your php version is below 5.4 or native. You'll have to upgrade it in you cpanel or whatever your server is using. Cheers!

Comment: upgrade your php to version 5.5 on your server

Answer (score 0):

you can actually do this

```
$autoload['drivers'] = array('cache');
```